How scale up a tensorflow graph nueral model that classifies the MUTAG mutagenicity database
We have a graph nueral model that identifies mutagens. It uses dropout, regularizer and dense layers. The input is from SMILES strings. It is a binary classifier. The invariant aggregate is "sum."
However, we have reason to believe that it doesn't scale to datasets larger than a hundred or so. How can we adapt the architecture?
Here's the model code:
def dense(units, activation="relu"):
  """A Dense layer with regularization (L2 and Dropout)."""
  regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_regularization)
  layer = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(
          units,
          activation=activation,
          kernel_regularizer=regularizer,
          kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=0.02), 
          bias_regularizer=regularizer),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
  ]) 
  return layer 


def _build_model(
    graph_tensor_spec,
    # Dimensions of initial states.
    node_dim=16,
    edge_dim=16,
    # Dimensions for message passing.
    message_dim=64,
    next_state_dim=64,
    # Number of message passing steps.
    num_message_passing=3,
    # Other hyperparameters.
):
  # Model building with Keras's Functional API starts with an input object
  # (a placeholder for the eventual inputs). Here is how it works for
  # GraphTensors:
  input_graph = tf.keras.layers.Input(type_spec=graph_tensor_spec)

  # IMPORTANT: All TF-GNN modeling code assumes a GraphTensor of shape []
  # in which the graphs of the input batch have been merged to components of
  # one contiguously indexed graph. (There are no edges between components,
  # so no information flows between them.)
  graph = input_graph.merge_batch_to_components()

  # Nodes and edges have one-hot encoded input features. Sending them through
  # a Dense layer effectively does a lookup in a trainable embedding table.
  def set_initial_node_state(node_set, *, node_set_name):
    # Since we only have one node set, we can ignore node_set_name.
    return tf.keras.layers.Dense(node_dim)(node_set[tfgnn.HIDDEN_STATE])
  def set_initial_edge_state(edge_set, *, edge_set_name):
    return tf.keras.layers.Dense(edge_dim)(edge_set[tfgnn.HIDDEN_STATE])
  graph = tfgnn.keras.layers.MapFeatures(
      node_sets_fn=set_initial_node_state, edge_sets_fn=set_initial_edge_state)(
          graph)


    for i in range(num_message_passing):
    graph = tfgnn.keras.layers.GraphUpdate(
        node_sets={
            "atoms": tfgnn.keras.layers.NodeSetUpdate(
                {"bonds": tfgnn.keras.layers.SimpleConv(
                     sender_edge_feature=tfgnn.HIDDEN_STATE,
                     message_fn=dense(message_dim),
                     reduce_type="sum",
                     receiver_tag=tfgnn.TARGET)},
                tfgnn.keras.layers.NextStateFromConcat(dense(next_state_dim)))}
    )(graph)

  # After the GNN has computed a context-aware representation of the "atoms",
  # the model reads out a representation for the graph as a whole by averaging
  # (pooling) nde states into the graph context. The context is global to each
  # input graph of the batch, so the first dimension of the result corresponds
  # to the batch dimension of the inputs (same as the labels).
  readout_features = tfgnn.keras.layers.Pool(
      tfgnn.CONTEXT, "mean", node_set_name="atoms")(graph)

  # Put a linear classifier on top (not followed by dropout).
  logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(readout_features)

  # Build a Keras Model for the transformation from input_graph to logits.
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_graph], outputs=[logits])
  return model

